# Проверить match 3 игру на наличие возможных ходов

Tags: разработка-игр

Добрый день!

Типичная match 3 игра:
Есть доска 8х8, на которой расположены фигуры шести разных цветов. Две фигуры можно поменять местами и, если после перестановки в ряд встают 3 фигуры одного цвета, то они удаляются (если больше, то тоже удаляются). В противном случае фигуры возвращаются на свои места. Ряды, в которых происходит проверка на совпадение цветов, могут быть только горизонтальные и вертикальные.

Как лучше проверить наличие возможных ходов? Интересует именно алгоритм. Я набросал варианты, когда возможны ходы. Единички - фигуры одного цвета, 0 - другие цвета:

00000000

00000000

00000000

00101000

00010000

00101000

00000000

00000000

................

00000000

00000000

00000000

01101100

00010000

01101100

00000000

00000000

................

00000000

00010000

00010000

00000000

11010110

00000000

00010000

00010000

................

00000000

00000000

00101000

00101000

00010000

00101000

00101000

00000000

Благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

Простой неоптимальный алгоритм:

- Идете по всем ячейкам
- Проверяете если есть соседи того же цвета на расстоянии 1 ячейки вокруг (по прямой и по диагонали)
- Проверяете есть ли соседи на расстоянии 2 ячеек по прямым
- Если есть, то проверяете лежат ли все три цвета по шаблону (два рядом и 1 смещен, или зигзагом) и можно ли сдвинуть цвет лежащий не на прямой чтобы получилась прямая (если какие-то ячейки могут буть заблокированы)